# How do I get the name of a menu in WordPress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I would like to know how to get menu name in header.
The problem is that I´ve got WordPress Theme that was created by another person. It works, but there is a problem. The website will be available in several languages and there is a secondary menu where you will need to display the word "Catalogue" in different languages. As I understand it, it is easier to take the name of the menu and print it out. I would be very grateful for any help.
Header.php consists of the following:

```
?>
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes();?>>
<head>

<meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset');?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="https://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<?php wp_head();?>
</head>
    
<body <?php body_class();?>>
<div id="page" class="site">
<header id="masthead" class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="head">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-3 d-flex align-items-center position-static">
                    <div class="burger-wrap">
                        <div class="burger "><span class="burger__text">CATALOGUE</span></div>
                        <div class="catalog">
                            <?php yasin_secondary_menu();?>
```

At the moment only the text that is written in `<span class="burger__text">CATALOGUE</span>` is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

**The first step you need to register using **function.php** add follow code=>**

```
register_nav_menus( array(
    'primary'   => __( 'Primary Menu', 'e-education' ),
    // 'secondary' => __( 'Secondary Menu', 'myfirsttheme' )
) );
```

**and you header.php add follow the code**

```
 <nav class="navbar justify-content-center  site-navigation">
      <?php
        wp_nav_menu(array(
           'theme_location'=>'primary'
        ) );
      ?>
   </nav>
```

> this code and function using you display successfully navbar

Comment: Thaks, it´s working but I just need the name of the secondary menu, the content is already there. The fact is that there's a burger icon and I need an inscription next to it for navigation.

Comment: I mean that I need to display secondary menu name instead of using this `<span class="burger__text">CATALOGUE</span>`

Answer (score 0):

Do you know location of the menu in the WordPress admin?

If  you do, you can echo all the menu items assigned to that location.

For example, if the menu location is `'secondary-menu'`, you can get the menu metadata using the `wp_get_nav_menu_object` function

```
$menuLocation = 'secondary-menu';

$menuLocations = get_nav_menu_locations();

$menuObject = (isset($menu_locations[$menuLocation]) ? wp_get_nav_menu_object($menuLocations[$menuLocation]) : null);

$menuName = (isset($menuObject->name) ? $menuObject->name : '');

echo $menuName;
```

You can also get the menu details if you know the menu slug. If the slug is 'catalogue', you could do `$menuName = wp_get_nav_menu_object("catalogue");` and then echo the `name` object just like the first method `echo $menuName->name;`

Comment: It almost helped me...but the problem is if I´m using `$menuName = wp_get_nav_menu_object("catalogue"); echo $menuName->name;` - It displays only "Catalogue" in both languages...
Coz I´ve got 2 secondary menus...Catalogue and Katalog.